# Database moddelling - Trying to understand

Tags: database, database-design, entity, diagram, erd

[image: erd]

Hey guys, I always get confused by this so it's not exactly my strong point :( Am I understanding correctly that the above example suggests:

One shop must have one or more clients
One client must have one shop

If there was to be a circle where at the end of the client arrow it suggests that the shop has zero or many clients.

I know it's a bad example but I am just trying to get my head around it. (Always get it the wrong way round)

Thanks very much, all help appreciated.

*it's just a quick example so I apologise for the bad naming convention of table names*

Comment: you're correct.  A shop can have one or many clients.  A client must have one and only one shop.  without the O on the crows foot, and instead the | it means mandatory.  I think of the O as optional and the | as a ! meaning YOU MUST!

Comment: There is no question in your post. PS There are many, many design methods & diagram styles. What is yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are understanding correctly.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate your quick response.